# Convert last hyphen in filename using BASH

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

I've been tasked with a major file rename project. Some of these files that I'll be renaming contain multiple hyphens. I need to swap the last hyphen in the name to an underscore in order for the files to be renamed to our new naming convention.

Can anyone explain to me why the last hyphen not being replaced with an underscore in the test code below?

```
#!/bin/bash

image_name="i-need-the-last-hyphen-removed.psd"

echo -e "Normal: ${image_name}"
echo "Changed: ${image_name/%-/_}"
```

The output I am looking for should mimic the following:

```
Normal: i-need-the-last-hyphen-removed.psd
Changed: i-need-the-last-hyphen_removed.psd
```

The script logic was created by following documentation found here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

I've tried escaping the hypen but that was not fruitful. I've given up, this will prove to be the most elegant solution versus using SED and/or BASH_REMATCH solutons I was working with in the past.

Any help would be great. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `echo "${image_name%-*}_${image_name##*-}"`

Comment: Take a look at `rename` command.

Comment: @AlexP.: +1 very nice.

Comment: @AlexP. Even short answers should be posted *as* answers, not comments.

Answer (score 2):

I'll suggest using rename tool for this kind of tasks. It's sed pattern similar.

```
rename 's/(.*)-/$1_/' *.psd
```

Since .* is greedy, that way last '-' will be catched, where (.*) is captured in group. Right part will not be changed.

With *.psd you will catch all psd files in current folder

Comment: This is what I received after issuing your suggestion. I then swapped the \1_ for a $1_ and had no luck.    


`Machine-Name$ rename 's/\(.*\)-/\1_/' *.psd
\1 better written as $1 at (eval 4) line 1.`

Comment: yes, $1 instead \1, i've tested and works here.. with $1

Comment: also when grouping no need for escaping (), i've edited answer. Now should be fine

Answer (score 1):

Huge thanks to @alex-p for the following suggestion. As I originally stated I didn't want to use SED or BASH_REMATCH or any other complex REGEX. This worked flawlessly.

echo "${image_name%-*}_${image_name##*-}"

Answer (score 0):

`${image_name/%-/_}"` would *only* work if the `-` was the very termination/suffix of the `$image_name` (like e.g. in `mystring-`).

Try using sed:

```
$> echo i-need-the-last-hyphen-removed.psd | sed -r 's/-([^-]*$)/_\1/'
i-need-the-last-hyphen_removed.psd
```

Comment: For educational purposes, can you explain to me what **back end** means?

Comment: @Jesse Riddle: Answer updated to be less obscure. The `back end` is taken from your source [link](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) : `If $substring matches back end of $string, substitute $replacement for $substring`

Comment: That is how I understood it. I was looking for $substring of "-" and using "%" to look from the back (essentially looking right -> left). Then my replacement was the "_". So I guess I don't understand why it didn't find the last hyphen using my logic. (Obviously it was wrong but I am trying to understand why.)

Comment: @Jesse Riddle: in my understanding, the `${string/%substring/replacement}` bash construct works on **exact** `substring` patterns ONLY, not trying to match anything like a shortest/longest pattern containing `substring` from right to left. Because `image_name` had plenty of characters next to the hyphen, this approach did not work. That's my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `sed` as:

```
sed -r "s/(.*)-(.*)/\1_\2/"
```

This will have two captured group (1. before last `-` 2. after last `-`)which will be concatenated with `_`
Or

```
sed -r "s/-([^-]*$)/_\1/"
```

This will have one captured group which will replace `-` with `_` and then the captured group will be concatenated at last.